# Raphael JS paper.set and multiple access

Tags: arrays, raphael

I try to create a set of Raphael objects, and animate them when window (for example) is clicked.

So this works: http://jsfiddle.net/6YdrG/2/

```
$(function() {
    (function () {

    var R = Raphael($('#svg')[0]);
    var i, circles = circlenumber = R.set();
    var v = [{offset: 0, circleVal: '+ 29 %'}, {offset: 120, circleVal: '+ 90 %'}, {offset: 240, circleVal: '+ 107 %'}, {offset: 360, circleVal: '+ 20 %'}];

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        circles[i] = R.circle(29+v[i].offset, 29, 10).attr({fill: '#000', stroke: 'none'});
        //circlenumber[i] = R.text(29+v[i].offset, 29, v[i].circleVal).attr({font: '12px JauresSemibold, serif', fill: '#fff'});
    };

    $(window).click(function() {
        console.log('click');
        for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            circles[i].animate(Raphael.animation({r: 28}, 800, 'easeInOut').delay(100*(i)));
        };
    });

    })();
});
```

But if you remove "//" to add the circlenumber[i] elements, it doesn't works anymore…

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the way you define `i`

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6YdrG/5/

You had `i` initialised as `R.Set()`.

Comment: Oh yeah! And, actualy, the way I define sets, `var circles = circlenumber = R.set();` doesn't works, and `var circles = R.set(), circlenumber = R.set();` does. Thanks!